# Paragraph element causes div to be pushed down

Tags: html, css

The width of my div is equal to the width of the browser. Whenever I place text inside the div, it gets pushed down and leaves a gap. If I remove the text, the div is placed back on its original position.

How do I remove this gap?

**Example**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #51c3cd;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #505050;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #b5e3e2
}
#header h3 {
  /* logo*/
  font-family: Darleston;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<header id="header">
  <h3>The Merry Knitters</h3> 
</header>
```

Comment: The paragraph (`p`) tag uses margins and padding on the element. You need to modify these selectors in order to prevent it from happening.

Comment: So make padding and margins zero?

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Comment: Where is <p> tag in your sample code?

Answer (score 3):

Because `<p>` tags include browser styling which add margins. Try a reset as follows:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I couldn't find any `p-element` in your sample code, I assumed you meant the `h3-element`. I managed to remove the gap you mention by adding the following code to your CSS:

```
#header h3 {
    margin: 0px;
    ...
}
```

**Example:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #51c3cd;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #505050;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #b5e3e2
}
#header h3 {
  /* logo*/
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Darleston;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<header id="header">
  <h3>The Merry Knitters</h3> 
</header>
```